# Changing vsftpd upload permissions

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I am trying to setup a local ftp server using vsftpd on ubuntu where anonymous users can upload and download files. However currently I am only able to upload files to the server but I am receiving a "550 Failed to open file. Error: Critical file transfer error". I believe this is because of a permission problem.

Files that are uploaded have a permission code of -rwx------ which does not allow for other users (anonymous) to read the files.

I am having troubles changing the permission of uploaded files. Here is my vsftpd.config file:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=0002
file_open_mode=0777
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
```

The permissions should be set to 755 because 777 - 002 = 775. However I am still getting -rwx------ or -rw-------.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anon_umask as suggested in the following post? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167389

Comment: You're very welcome!